# Generate unique ID code with initials and birthday in excel or R

Tags: r, excel

I don't know anything about programming. I need to generate an `ID` from a kids initials birthday and teacher number. I don't know if that can be done easily in excel or I should use R for example. What I have are columns like this in excel

```
 Grade     Teacher  Students Initials  Birthday
```

I need the `ID` to be generated to start with `#4` than followed by the `grade` then the teacher has an assigned `2` digit number the kids initials substitute numbers `1/26` for each letter `A-Z` (e.g RD would be `1804`) birthday month day

So 
kid in grade `6` teacher `#05` initials `RD` birthday `June 06` would be `460518040606`

I have about 2`000` kids so I would appreciate some help

Thank you

Comment: Please show few lines of your dataset.

Comment: With only these values it will be likely, not be guaranteed that the ID is unique.

Comment: This is a pretty easy task in R. If you just show a bunch of lines of your dataset, you'll receive an answer faster than you might think. On the other hand, if your data are in Excel, you might need to install additional R libraries (for instance `gdata`) or to convert your file in the `.csv` format.

Comment: If length of ID is not an issue, could probably append 1 to 2000 to the 2000 kids.  e.g. adapting @akrun's method slightly, `with(dat, paste0(4, Grade, Teacher, Init, Bday, sprintf("%04d",1:2000)))` to get unique IDs.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure whether this exercise will generate an unique ID.  Here is one method to generate the ID based on the conditions mentioned

```
Init <-  sapply(strsplit(dat$Initials,""),
             function(x) {l1 <- match(x,LETTERS)
              sprintf('%02d%02d', l1[1], l1[2])})
```

Or the above step could be done with `substr`

```
 Init <-  sprintf('%02d%02d', match(substr(dat$Initials,1,1), LETTERS),
                       match(substr(dat$Initials, 2,2), LETTERS))
```

Or a variation is

```
 Init <- do.call(`sprintf`, c('%02d%02d', lapply(1:2, function(x) 
                      match(substr(dat$Initials, x,x), LETTERS))))
```

Or using `mgsub` from `qdap`

```
library(qdap)
Init <- mgsub(LETTERS, sprintf('%02d',1:26), dat$Initials) 

Bday <- format(as.Date(paste(dat$Birthday, 2004), '%B %d %Y'), '%m%d')

paste0(4, dat$Grade, dat$Teacher, Init, Bday)
#[1] "460518190606" "440701040720" "470801190518" "450118040825"
```

#### data

```
 dat <- data.frame(Grade=c(6,4,7,5), Teacher=c('05', '07', '08', '01'), 
          Students=c(3,5,7,8), Initials=c('RS','AD', 'AS', 'RD'), 
           Birthday=c('June 06', 'July 20', 'May 18', 'August 25'),
           stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do that in Excel quite easily. Assume that `A2` contains the Grade, `B2` the 2 digit teacher code, `C2` the students' initials and `D2` the birthday as a date. Then the following formula in `E2` will do (please check whether your system uses semicolons `;` or simple commas `,` for the Excel formula, mine does obviopusly use the semicolon):

```
="4" & A2 & B2 & TEXT(CODE(LEFT(C2;1))-64;"00") & TEXT(CODE(RIGHT(C2;1))-64;"00") & 
                 TEXT(MONTH(D2);"00")&TEXT(DAY(D2);"00")
```

**Explanation**

- The `TEXT`function is used for formatting the string, the string formatter `"00"` means to print in 2 digits and add `0's` if needed.
- The `CODE` function calculates the ascii code of a given character. `A` codes as `65` that's why you have to substract `64`.
- `LEFT` and `RIGHT` return the given number of characters from the left and the right  of the string respectively.
- `DAY` and `MONTH` return the day and the month of a given date.

Hope that helps.